# PHP DATE ignoring day number 'z' and jumps to ELSE

Tags: php, date

I'm trying to piece together a script that will output a unique message every day of the year, so obviously this would be 365 messages. The code that I'm testing sadly jumps straight to `else`, rather than respecting the `date 'z'`. I suspect that it’s a problem with my code, here’s what I've attempted so far:

```
<?php

  $date = date('z');

  if($date == "41"){
    echo "Test Message One";
  }
  elseif($date == "42"){
    echo "Test Message Two";
  }
  else{
    echo "Sadly your script does not work";
  }

?>
```

Comment: In my timezone `echo date('z');` is `43`.  What is it in your timezone?

Comment: day 41 = 11th February, day 42 = 12th February.... what's today's date? It's the 13th February where I am

Comment: _obviously this would be 365 messages_.. 366 times this year though. Also, rather than writing 365 / 366 if else statements, why not create an array of messages and get it from there.

Comment: Yep!!! spot on lol... stupid me! :)

Answer (score 1):

Please note that `date('z')` is indexed at 0 instead of 1 (as I learned the hard the way). You will have to add +1 to your day of the year.

```
$date = date('z') + 1;
```

Comment: Hi Err, thanks for that. I knew that the index started from 0 but I was several days out which ended up being the problem. Will add that to my code through. +1.

Answer (score 0):

*There is nothing wrong with the code as such but more so with the assignment of the day numbers within the code, thanks to [Michael Berkowsk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/541091/michael-berkowski), [Mark Baker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/324584/mark-baker) and [putvande](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2539720/putvande) for pointing this out. Rather than calculating the day numbers you need in your head it's advisable to use Google or [epoch day numbers](http://www.epochconverter.com/epoch/daynumbers.php).*

*Notably it's important to note that php date starts from 0 to 365, this means:*

- Jan 1st = 0
- Jan 2nd = 01

*If your want to Jan 1st = 1, Jan 2nd = 2 and so forth simply edit your code to look something like this:*

- `$date = date('z') + 1;` credit to [Err](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1321183/err) for this.